# Rails - Better approach when appending values to a JsonB field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on populating a jsonB field whenever a Candidate record is entered/moved to a new entrypoint.

I'm currently using the ff. approach:

(They can be called multiple times and will just append the new entry point to the jsonB field [entry])

```
// Method in Candidate model
def log_entry(value)
  self.entry = Array(self.entry) << { val: value, timestamp: Time.now.to_i }
end

def log_entry!(value)
  self.log_entry(value)
  self.save
end
```

Called on every controller entrypoint

```
ca = Candidate.new(name: 'John Doe')
ca.log_entry('Point 1')
ca.save
```

Could also be called like this when moved to a new entry point

```
ca = Candidate.find id
ca.log_entry!('Point 2')
```

The record will look like this after calling `log_entry` twice:
Candidate Model

```
Name: 'John Doe'
Entry: [{ val: 'Point 1', timestamp: '<time>' }, { val: 'Point 2', timestamp: '<time>' }]
```

So far, the above approach is achieving the desired result. But I have an impression that the code is too cluttered and that there's a better approach for this.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChristianBruckmayer I disagree. It could be rewritten to fit their scope, but it would need a lot of additional information and a big chunk of extra code before it wouldn't get shot down lightning fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably seems/feels cluttered simply because this is breaking [single responsibility principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). You don’t give the context on why you’re keeping what seems to be an access log for each of these `Candidate` objects, but when you think about it, it should not be the `Candidates` responsibility to record why and when it was accessed. By coupling these together in this way, whenever two callers to the controller entry point happen at the same time, you will either get a `StaleObjectError` or simply drop one of the log entries.

Also by the way this is currently coded, to have the entry log recorded, you have to manually call a separate method.  This makes it so that anyone that later adds a `Candidate.find(x)` call somewhere, would need to also call the `log_entry` method after retrieving the `Candidate`.

What I would suggest is two things:

1. Separate this access log storage to it’s own object that it’s a running log so that it can easily be updated by multiple sources at the same time.  This would be achievable through breaking the `log_entry` content storage to it’s own object, and linking it to the `Candidate` object through a `has_many` relationship.
2. Creating a new concern that can by mixed into any models that need this access logging, which overrides any accessor methods like `find` or `find_by` so that it inserts a new `log_entry` before returning the found `Candidate`.  If you want to get elaborate with this, you can use a [decorator pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to allow access logging to easily be attached to any existing method definition through using a decorator to modify the inner workings of the method.

**If you need the coupling:**

ince you need the coupling, then I would suggest still breaking the logic out into a concern so that you can decorate the appropriate methods that need to update these log entries. And utilize [Optimistic Locking](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) and some retry logic on updates to make sure data is not lost during concurrent requests. This will remove the clunkiness of multiple knowledge, confine it to one place, and remove the case of accidental data loss.

Some rough code (just the `find` method modification) would look something like the following:

```rb
# — Candidate Class —
def find(id, reason=“”)
  super(id).tap do |candidate|
    Array(candidate.log_entry) << { ... }
    candidate.save
  rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError => ex
    # do some logging here
    retry
  end
end
```

The above modification of the find method will find the object requested, record the log entry on it, retry recording in the case of a stale object error, and return the object found. This way there is no need for duplicated code anywhere else in your Rails application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I could use that in my other cases. But for this one, I need to stick with the current approach of using a single jsonb field.

Comment: Since you need the coupling, then I would suggest still breaking the logic out into a concern so that you can decorate the appropriate methods that need to update these log entries. And utilize [Optimistic Locking](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) and some retry logic on updates to make sure data is not lost during concurrent requests. This will remove the clunkiness of multiple knowledge, confine it to one place, and remove the case of accidental data loss.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer to include this flushed out a little under an additional “if you need the coupling” section.

Comment: Awesome! I honestly forgot about the possibility of StaleObjectError. Thanks for those Infos!